# Assign pointer to iterator

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I need to deallocate and then allocate a pointer in the vector iterator . Is it Ok to assign a pointer to iterator as given below?

```
   VEC_SECS m_vec;
   m_vec.push_back(new CSecs);       
   VEC_SECS::iterator iter = m_vec.begin();

   for (iter ; iter != m_vec.end(); ++iter)
   {
          CSecs *p = *iter;
          delete p;         
          p = new CSecs;
          *iter = p;
   }
```

Comment: that code would fail any normal core review

Comment: @VJovic what is the best way to take care of the situation

Comment: *Best defense - not be there!* - You didn't say what you want to do, so can't give better advice, but not to do the above.

Comment: VJovic: During the iteration, there is a possibility for deleting the pointer iterator holds and then allocate a new pointer with new data. I know that it is not good technique, But I dont see any other option

Comment: A slightly better option would be to allocate a new object before deleting the existing one. This at least ensures that you don't end up with a dangling pointer in the vector if creating a new one fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do not assign pointer to iterator, you just ovewrite the element iterator points to. I take it your `VEC_SECS` is a vector of pointers, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why so complex? I'd just write

```
VEC_SECS m_vec;
m_vec.push_back(new CSecs);       
for (VEC_SECS::iterator iter = m_vec.begin(); iter != m_vec.end(); ++iter)
{
       CSecs& obj = **iter;
       obj = CSecs();
       // or just **iter = CSecs();
}
```

Comment: Although this requires CSecs to be assignable. Eventually one could question whether a container of pointers and dynamic allocations are needed in the first place.